# WordPress Divi shortcode adding

Tags: php, wordpress, divi-theme

## **WordPress Divi Theme shortcode adding problem**

My Divi version is 3.20.1. I am trying to add my own custom shortcode in the website. However, when I add this shortcode, the elements displayed using this shortcode appear both in the "Edit page" area top section besides the main page.

```
add_shortcode( "Btx_Show_Testimonial_Main_Page", 'lantry_btx_fun_Main_Page_Show_Testimonial');
function lantry_btx_fun_Main_Page_Show_Testimonial(){
     include_once LANTRY_BITECHX_SHORTCODE_DIR_PATH."views/Main_Page_testimonial_show.php"; 
}
```

**My question is, how can I remove this from the "Edit page" section ??**

I provided some screenshot.

[Divi module Image Option Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM8ZE.png)
[Show top of the post page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRCHw.jpg)

---

When I remove Divi this problem will be solved. But I need to use Divi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a adminuser is logged in and if not execute your function hope this helps but now you have to always log out or use incognito mode to see if its there:

```js
add_shortcode( "Btx_Show_Testimonial_Main_Page", 'lantry_btx_fun_Main_Page_Show_Testimonial');
function lantry_btx_fun_Main_Page_Show_Testimonial(){
     if (current_user_can( 'update_core' )) {
          return;
      }
     include_once LANTRY_BITECHX_SHORTCODE_DIR_PATH."views/Main_Page_testimonial_show.php"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem comes from DIVI but from your shortcode. Please attach the content of your file `Main_Page_testimonial_show.php`

The shortcode callback shouldn't produce an output but should return the result.

You can find this on documentation website [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/). Please pay attention to

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce an
> output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is
> to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly
> will lead to unexpected results. This is similar to the way filter
> functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side
> effects from the call since you cannot control when and where they are
> called from.

Answer (score 0):

Here, simply you can create the shortcode in the **functions.php** file and on your **Page/Posts** you can use the Text Module and add the **[shortcode].**